# How do I stop my React application from continuously updating an element based on an input field?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, twitter

In this program I'm in we are currently developing a "twitter clone" but without a backend. We are trying to use React purely to make it look like Twitter and be a mockup of it.

At the moment, we have an input field and a "tweet" button. However, what happens is we type something in, press Tweet, and then each individual tweet updates with each change to the input field. How do we stop it from doing that and just display each individual tweet as it was when we pressed Tweet? Below is my Feed component and then below that is my Tweet component:

Feed.js:

```
// // import {Component} when building a class component
import React, {Component} from 'react';
// // importing our CSS file from src>css
import '../css/Feed.css';
import Tweets from './Tweets';

const GENERIC_Tweets_USERNAME = "Username" , GENERIC_Tweets_BODY = "Body", GENERIC_Tweets_TIMESTAMP = "Timestamp"; 
class Feed extends Component {
    // // constructor method available to us in class components
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      tweets: [],
      username: GENERIC_Tweets_USERNAME,
      body: GENERIC_Tweets_BODY,
      timestamp: GENERIC_Tweets_TIMESTAMP,
    }
  }
  addTweets() {
    console.log(this.state.body);
 
    let tweets = this.state.tweets;
    tweets.push(
      {
        id: Date.now()
      }
    );
    this.setState(
      {
        tweets: this.state.tweets
      }
    );
  }
  handleTweet = (event) => {
    this.setState({body:event.target.value});
    console.log(this.state.body);
  }
  deleteTweets(id){
    let newTweetsArr = this.state.tweets;
    newTweetsArr.map((tweets, index) => {
      if (id === tweets.id) {
        newTweetsArr.splice(index,1);
      }
    });
    this.setState(
      {
        tweets: newTweetsArr
      }
    );
  }

  

  // // render method - render what is returned (JSX) onto the browser
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="div-board">
          <div className="row">
          <div>
            <input onChange={this.handleTweet} placeholder="What's Happening?"></input>
        </div>
        <div>
     {this.state.description}
     <button className="btn btn-success add-button" onClick={this.addTweets.bind(this)}>
       Tweet
     </button> 
   </div>
            {
              this.state.tweets.map(tweets => {
                return <Tweets key={tweets.id} id={tweets.id} deleteHandler={this.deleteTweets.bind(this)} body={this.state.body} />
              })
            }
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default Feed;
```

Tweets.js:

````
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
// const GENERIC_Tweets_USERNAME = "Username" , GENERIC_Tweets_BODY = "Body", GENERIC_Tweets_TIMESTAMP = "Timestamp"; 
class Tweets extends Component {
    // // ignore constructor method for now
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.usernameContent = React.createRef();
    this.bodyContent = React.createRef();
    this.timestampContent = React.createRef();
    this.state = {
      // username: GENERIC_Tweets_USERNAME,
      // body: GENERIC_Tweets_BODY,
      // timestamp: GENERIC_Tweets_TIMESTAMP,
      // editMode: false
    }
  }  
  // handleSave() {
  //   this.setState({
  //     username: this.usernameContent.current.value,
  //     body: this.bodyContent.current.value,
  //     timestamp: this.timestampContent.current.value,
  //     // editMode: false
  //   });
  // }
  handleDelete() {
    this.props.deleteHandler(this.props.id);
  }
//   // render method return JSX
render(){
    let usernameElement, bodyElement, timestampElement, buttonArea; 
    // if (this.state.editMode){
    //   usernameElement = <textarea ref={this.usernameContent} className="username-textarea" defaultValue={this.state.username}></textarea>;
    //   bodyElement = <textarea ref={this.bodyContent} className="body-textarea" defaultValue={this.state.body}></textarea>;
    //   timestampElement = <textarea ref={this.timestampContent} className="timestamp-textarea" defaultValue={this.state.timestamp}></textarea>;
    //   buttonArea = <div><button className="btn btn-primary" onClick={this.handleSave.bind(this)}>Save</button></div>;
    // }
    // else{
      usernameElement = <h5 className="card-username">{this.props.username}</h5>;
      bodyElement = <p>{this.props.body}</p>; 
      console.log(this.props);
      timestampElement = <p>{this.props.timestamp}</p>;
      buttonArea = <div>
      <button className="btn btn-danger" onClick={this.handleDelete.bind(this)}>Delete</button>
      </div>;
    // }
    return (
      <div className='col-sm-6'>
        <div className="card card-view">
          <div className="card-synopsis">
                {usernameElement}
                {bodyElement}
                {timestampElement}
                {buttonArea}
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    );
  }
}
// Tweets.defaultProps = {
//     username: "Username",
//    body: "Body",
//     timestamp: "Timestamp",
  // };
  Tweets.propTypes = {
    username: PropTypes.string
  };
  export default Tweets;```
````

Answer (score 0):

First, update your function, by adding the body parameter and by creating a new array out of the existing body, instead of mutating it. Also, if you write your function as an anonymous one, you won't have to bind `this` to it (in the render() function).:

```
 addTweets = () => {
    this.setState({
        tweets: this.state.tweets.concat({  id: Date.now(), body: this.state.body }),
        body: ''
      });
  }
```

Then, correct your `render()` function:

```
 {
              this.state.tweets.map(tweets => {
                return <Tweets key={tweets.id} id={tweets.id} deleteHandler={this.deleteTweets.bind(this)} body={tweets.body} />
              })
  }
```

Comment: That works perfectly! Thank you very much.